# How to start passenger in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment, passenger

I'm starting the `Rails 3` application with the following command:

`passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d`

but how do I tell `passenger` to start the application in `production` environment?

Comment: How to add SSL parameter

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d -e production
```

Side note: always check the help, `passenger start --help` would have told you the same.

Comment: why this -a 0.0.0. ?? pls reply.

Comment: This tells the server to listen on all IP addresses. If you remove it, you will only be able to access it from localhost.

Comment: @BenoitGarret It is running as daemon process how can i stop it?

Comment: When you start passenger as a daemon, it will tell you the location of the PID file. Simply kill the process with that pid like this: sudo kill $(cat path/to/pidfile.pid)

Comment: I have setup the passenger with nginx but there is no connection between these two rails do not start and browser said error

Comment: How could I add paramerer SSL=true in passenger

Comment: How about running this command when computer starts? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment configuration, you might need this:

```
sudo passenger-config restart-app /
```