# Start Phusion Passenger from Ruby code

Tags: ruby, passenger, phusion

I'd like to start the server from inside my gem code, the way Rails starts Unicorn, Puma, Webrick or whatever with "rails server". I'd like to have a binary like "mygem server" and that would start Passenger.

I tried with backticks but I'd like to avoid spawning another process if it's at all possible. (Also, I lost the stdout from Passenger when I did that.)

Is the command line the only way to start Passenger?

Comment: what command are you using (with backticks) to start Passenger?
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7260981/6324558) seems to start the Passenger daemon, (simply redirect the output of the command to a log file in bash to retrieve your STDOUT)

Comment: I use `passenger start` or some variation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passanger is a C++ "gem" that actually runs the Ruby layer separated from the root server process.

The developers consider this approach to protect the server from Ruby related issues (I think this isn't necessary, but it's definitely interesting).

This leaves you with a couple of options:

1. You could use [`Kernel.exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) which **replaces** the current process with the command line you provide.
2. You could use another server, such as [Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma), [Iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine), [Agoo](https://github.com/ohler55/agoo) or whatever you fancy.

   Each server has their advantages and their disadvantages so test and pick and choose.

   I know from experience that you can start all of them from within a block of code (or so I recall).

Comment: I didn't think about Kernel.exec; I think that's the way to go, as I'm rather keep on Passenger for unrelated reasons. Thanks so much!